# Read variable by name from server.xml

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, websphere-liberty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>

  <variable 
    name="temp" 
    value="Something" />
</server>
```

How can I programmatically read `temp` from the xml file from a Java based web application?

Was trying:

```
String temp = System.getenv("temp");
```

Comment: Look up XML parsers?

Comment: @Zephyr should there not be something available out of the box since its contained in `server.xml`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options you have to do this:

## 1. Using MicroProfile Config

In `server.xml`:

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>mpConfig-1.3</feature>
  ....
</featureManager>

<variable  name="temp"  value="Something" />
```

Then inject into any CDI bean:

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "temp")
String temp;
```

## 2. Store the variable in JNDI with `<jndiEntry>`

In `server.xml`:

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
  ....
</featureManager>

<jndiEntry jndiName="config/foo" value="whatever"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="config/bar" value="${temp}"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="config/configDir" value="${server.config.dir}"/>
```

With resource injection in a servlet or EJB (or other managed class):

```
@Resource(lookup = "config/foo")
String foo;
```

Or programmatic JNDI lookup:

```
String configDir = InitialContext.doLookup("config/configDir");
```

## 3. Using environment variables:

This approach requires you to set environment variables in `${server.config.dir}/server.env`, or in the environment of the process that starts the Liberty server. Everything in here will end up in the server JVM's env.

```
temp=Something
foo=bar
```

Then get as env var in an application:

```
String temp = System.getenv("temp");
```

Comment: In addition to the jndiEntry method, there are two SPIs for retrieving variables:  VariableRegistry and WsLocationAdmin, both in com.ibm.wsspi.kernel.service.location. SPI code can only be used from a user feature, though, so a jndiEntry is probably the best choice. 

For more information see 'Programmatic access to location properties' here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_dirs.html